# Get Number of emails sent by user in postfix

Tags: postfix, centos6

I'm using postfix,I have an email user test@mydomain.com 
How I can get total number of messages sent by this user ;

Iam trying to search in 
/var/spool/mail

with no success

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003732/postfix-how-to-count-all-outgoing-emails

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [pflogsumm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pflogsumm)

> Pflogsumm is a log analyzer/summarizer for the Postfix MTA.  It is
>   designed to provide an over-view of Postfix activity, with just enough
>   detail to give the administrator a "heads up" for potential trouble
>   spots.
>
> Pflogsumm generates summaries and, in some cases, detailed reports of
>   mail server traffic volumes, rejected and bounced email, and server
>   warnings, errors and panics.